# vue-instagram : images showing as icons, even though src/url is correct

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, instagram-api

I'm using the vue-instagram component to display images from my own instagram account.. 
The url's are correct (when i inspect element, and open the url in new tab, the image shows up...), but it only shows up as an icon (see image below)..

Here's my code : (boilerplate from example) :

```
<template>
<vue-instagram token="209161622.1677ed0.cd18b9a41f0c4a53b646b8f012f465ab" :count="5" mediaType="image">
    <template slot="feeds" slot-scope="props">
        <!-- <li class="fancy-list"> {{ props.feed.link }} </li> -->
        <img :src="props.feed.link" />

    </template>
    <template slot="error" slot-scope="props">
        <div class="fancy-alert"> {{ props.error.error_message }} </div>
    </template>
</vue-instagram>
```

```
import VueInstagram from 'vue-instagram'

export default {
components: {
    VueInstagram,
    }
}
</script>
```

As you see from the image below, it only display the icon, not the picture itself :

[image]

Here is the rendered HTML : 
[image]

Any idea what i'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: Your URLs aren't images, they are HTML pages.

Comment: @Phil : Have you used the plugin and know how this behaves ? This thing keeps questioning my logic :)

Comment: No but I suspect it allows you to link to an Instagram **post** and not directly to an image. From a brief bit of research, it doesn't appear like Instagram makes it particularly easy to get a direct image URL

Comment: I see in your vue-devtools screenshot, there's an object call `images`. What's in that?

Comment: Checking it out riiight now.. 

Hmm. it might seem that the author of vue-instagram didn't add the css he was using.. that might be the issue here.. *dooh*

Comment: wow.. i didn't find this page.. This actually solved my issue.. :) Maybe i'm just too tired after 12 hours of constant programming.. : )

Will you post this up as a solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your links are to the post (an HTML page), not directly to the image so they cannot be displayed as images.

From snooping around the [component's Github page](https://github.com/kevinongko/vue-instagram/blob/master/docs/index.html), it seems you want

```html
<img :src="props.feed.images.low_resolution.url" alt="Image">
```